# Which word can I use for "abundant light"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Which word can I use to describe too much light, i.e., when I have switched on 3 bulbs while there was a need for only 1 bulb?

Comment: Any reason why you couldn't simply say _overly bright_?  Does it need to be a single word?  Just curious.

Comment: I hadn’t realized that *Thesaurus vulgaris* had gone extinct. I’m sure he would have settled this question right away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the light is too bright, you might use terms *[dazzling](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dazzling)* or *[glaring](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/glaring)*.  If instead you refer to cost of running several bulbs, say *[extravagant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/extravagant)* or *[wasteful](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wasteful)*.

Answer (score 2):

The light is ***blinding*** if excessive light, and not excessive power bills, is what bothers you.

Answer (score 1):

If positive: *brilliant*

If negative: *glaring*, *blinding*

Comment: As a noun, you'd use *brilliance*.

Answer (score 1):

***overlit***

The place has been overlit: it has been provided with more than the required amount of lighting (intensity), such as an overlit stadium for an all-night match.

Answer (score 0):

*Excessive* does it for me. The effect, if dazzling or glaring, or the power consumption, if extravagant or wasteful, might lead to different choices (q.v.), but if it's simply a matter of more light than was needed or desirable, then ...